# Setting cookies in external domains in a web service

Tags: javascript, php, http, cookies

A website, let's call it customerwebsite.com, loads a script from our domain. Let's call our domain trackingwebsite.com. This script calls a web service on the server (written in PHP) that logs some things and then sets a cookie to identify the user later.

The Set-Cookie header gets returned correctly. So far so good. However, on the next request that the script makes to the web service, the cookie is not sent back.

I'm setting the cookie with an expire time of 10 years, with the domain set to .customerwebsite.com (I've also tried this with .trackingwebsite.com to be sure)

After some googling and reading through various vague answers I think I've distilled that this set-up is not possible.

Am I correct in assuming that the web service cannot set cookies, and that the script calling the web service has to take care of getting and setting cookies and sending this to the web service if required?

Comment: HTTP requests initiated by the script will be from the origin of the surrounding page ("customerwebsite.com"), and thus it won't be able to set or read cookies from your domain. People use `<img>` tags for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sounds obvious. What I think we're going to do is have the web service send back cookie information it needs to set (for example as part of the JSON-response), and then have the script set, read, and generally manage the cookies. This should work, right?